# Add Duplicate HTTP Response Headers in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, http-headers, httpresponse

I am looking for adding duplicate HTTP headers in the http response in Nodejs, something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Length: 1234567
Content-Type: video/ogg
Content-type: multipart/byteranges; boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
```

I am using the http module provided by Nodejs and when I send the response header, I can only define one "Content-Type" header:

```
var header = {};
header['Content-Type'] = "video/ogg";
```

or

```
header['Content-Type'] = "multipart/byteranges; boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES";
```

Is it possible to include both "Content-Type" in the response? Thanks.

Comment: I assume using `header['Content-type']` (one letter is lower case) does not work?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick reply. I have tried to put both 'Content-type' and 'Content-Type' into header, but on the client side I can only see whichever defined last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is an [open issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2750) with Node.js itself. You could circumvent this by using one Content-Type with comma separated values, [using this patch](https://raw.github.com/jolira/node-subversion-hub/master/lib/http-patch.js), or if possible, implementing an `X-Content-Type` header. Multiple `X-` header values are currently concatenated into one.